# php buffer reader in socket programming

Tags: php, sockets, buffer

I need to connect with a server of another company. they send me a manual that says:
........................................................................................................

- Firstly open a socket using IP: 10.7.4.30 and port:91
- then send request as

  `/connectToMe?user=abc&key=539&cid=153648&code=5586`
- Simply write above line in socket and do not close the socket. 
  for getting the response you must use Buffer reader in socket programming.
- sample responce code:

  `cid::status:description`

........................................................................................................

Now, the problem is, I never use buffer reader and I don't have any idea about socket programming. But I have to do this.
I've googled for php socket connection and found this:

```
$host = "10.7.4.30";
$port = 91;

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
$result = socket_listen($socket, SOMAXCONN) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");
$spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
$input = socket_read($spawn, 10000, PHP_NORMAL_READ) or die("Could not read input\n");
echo $input;
$output = "Hello PHP";
socket_write($spawn,$output."\n", strlen($output) + 1) or die("Could not write output\n");
socket_close($spawn);
socket_close($socket);
```

but this shows, **unable to bind address[99]**. 
* I need to know how to connect to that server.
* how to request any data in their given format
* how to read the response code.
please help me. give some sample code or concept or some tutorial links.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks,

I got the solution on the following link.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/418814/Socket-Programming-in-PHP

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going through the PHP Documentation?

[Socket Examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php)

There's a client connection example. It shows how to connect to a socket, and how to read data back from the TCP/IP socket.